# Jmeter: Response time decreased AND throughput also decreased

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

I am running my jmeter script for almost a week and observed an interesting thing today. Below is the scenario:

**Overview:** I am gradually increasing the load on the application. In my last test I gave load of 100 users on the app and today I increased the load to 150 users.

**Result of 150 users test:**

1. Response time of the requests decreased compared to the last test. (Which is a good sign)
2. Throughput decreased drastically to half of what I got in the previous test with less load.
3. Received 225 errors while executing the test.

*My questions are:*

1. What could be the possible reason for such strange behavior of throughput? Why did throughput decrease instead of increasing with the increasing load?
2. Did I get good response time as many of my requests failed?

**NOTE:** Till 100 users test throughput was increasing with the increasing load of users.
Can anyone please help me with this question. I am a new bee in performance testing. **Thanks in Advance!!**
Also, would like to request if anyone can suggest good articles/site etc on finding performance bottleneck and learning crucial things in performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably these 225 requests which failed returned failure immediately therefore average response time decreased, that's why you should be looking into i.e. [Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime/) chart and pay more attention to [percentiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) as mean response time can mask the real problem.

With regards to the bottleneck discovery, make sure to collect as much information from the server side as you can, i.e.

- CPU, RAM, Network, Disk usage from [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)
- [Slow queries log](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/LATEST/diagnostics/slow_extended.html) from the database
- "heaviest" functions and largest objects from the [profiling tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) for your application

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri for helping me out !!